# Bayes with extra conditioning

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

I have doubt in following proble. Can any 1 please tell whether i did it correctly or not.

> A patient named Fred is tested for a disease called conditionitis, a medical condition that afflicts 1% of the population. The test result is positive, i.e., the test claims that Fred has the disease. Fred, who tested positive for conditionitis as above, decides to get tested a second time. The new test is independent of the original test (given his disease status) and has the same sensitivity and specificity. Unfortunately for Fred, he tests positive a second time. Find the probability that Fred has the disease, given the evidence in conditioning on both test results

(Although this is already mentioned in [Finding the probability that someone has the disease, given they test positive on two tests](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2944252/finding-the-probability-that-someone-has-the-disease-given-they-test-positive-o) ) i have a doubt here. I have gone through all of the post but could not find where i have doubt ... kindly have a look below)

> My approach:

D = Fred has disease; $T_1 =$ first test result positive ;

$T_2= $ second test result positive
$P(D/T_1, T_2) =\frac{ P(T_1,T_2/D)*P(D)}{P(T_1,T_2)}$

Here "," denotes "intersection"

Here in problem, it is mentioned that test results are independent to each other. SO can i take here $P(T_1 \cap T_2)=P(T_1)*P(T_2) = 0.059^2=0.003481$ -->(1)

[Due to this small fraction i am getting $P(D/T_1, T_2) > 2$ which is nonsense. It means $T_1, T_2$ not independent but problem and common sense says they should be independent. Somewhere i feel i am thinking wrongly

But we can also calculate $P(T_1 \cap T_2) = P(D)P(T_1 \cap T_2/D)+P(D^c)P(T_1 \cap T_2/D^c) \\ = 0.01*0.95^2+0.99*0.05^2 \\ = 0.0115$ -->(2)

This is giving me correct answer as given in textbook. Please tell me where i made mistake.

Comment: Sir please have a look now ... it's typing mistake in latex.

Comment: My Question - Is $P(T_1,T_2)=P(T_1)*P(T_2)$ as T_1, T_2 are independent as mentioned in given problem. But this is giving me probability >2 .

Comment: Since $P(T_1,T_2/D)\le P(T_1,T_2)$ and $P(D)\le1$, you can't have $\frac{ P(T_1,T_2/D)P(D)}{P(T_1,T_2)}>1$. Your assumption of independence does not hold: in *"The new test is independent of the original test (given his disease status)"*, the parenthesis means something (*"given"* $=$ conditioning). But I admit it's not entirely obvious from the problem statement.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut thank you sir