# Conditional Probability Twice

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

An disease is caught by $1$% of people. There is a test for the disease. The probability that the test is positive when someone has the disease is $0.98$; the probability that the test is negative when someone does not have the disease is $0.95$. A woman takes the test for the disease.

The woman gets a second opinion and the test is repeated independently. The
second test also shows a positive for the disease. Given this, what is the probability
that the woman has the disease?

How would I solve this ? I defined two events. Let $A$ denote the event the woman tests positive,$B$ denote the event woman has the disease, and $C$ denote event woman tests positive twice. I need $P(B|A).$ I know $P(B)=0.01$, $P(A|B)=0.98$,$P(A^c|B^c)=0.95$, so $P(A|B^c)=0.05$.

Attempt:

$P(C) = P(C|B)P(B) + P(C|B^c)P(B^c) = (0.98)^2(0.01)+(0.05)^2(0.99) = 0.012079 $

We want to calculate $P(B|C)$ = $\frac{P(C|B)P(B)}{P(C)} = \frac{0.98^20.01}{0.012079} = \frac{9604}{12079} = 0.795$.

Comment: Hmm... by "second opinion", do you mean the woman wants to take the test again? But the question's clear enough, just asking 

Comment: @TheMather-orratherAMather Yes the woman takes the test again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate Pr(Diseased | 2 Positive Tests)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198677/how-to-calculate-prdiseased-2-positive-tests)

Comment: @Andreas Please check my edit

Comment: @TheMather-orratherAMather Can you check my edit please ?

Comment: I think you're correct! Do you just want to verify your answer?

Comment: @TheMather-orratherAMather Yes please, I want to verify my answer, especially the method. Like is it correct that $P(C|B) = P(A|B)^2$? Is this because the test is repeated independently ?

Comment: Yes, that's right 